# Windows 7 x64 and Java 8: a path to development.properties

Tags: java, deployment, properties, settings

Windows 7 x 64. Java 1.8.0_152-b16 is installed to "C:\Program Files\Java\jre1.8.0_152" I am trying to use deployment.properties file to specify some Java settings. For that, I used the following doc: https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/technotes/guides/deploy/properties.html

There was no folder C:\Windows\Sun, so I created C:\Windows\Sun\Java\Deployment on my own. In this folder, I created deployment.config with the following content:
deployment.system.config=file:///C:/Windows/Sun/Java/Deployment/deployment.properties
But the file deployment.properties in this folder wasn't used.

Then, I tried to place deployment.config and deployment.properties in "C:\Program Files\Java\jre1.8.0_152\lib\". In this case, deployment.config was the following:
deployment.system.config=C:/Program\ Files/Java/jre1.8.0_152/lib/deployment.properties
Again, deployment.properties wasn't used.

Next, I tried to use a user-level deployment.properties in C:\Users\Racoon\AppData\LocalLow\Sun\Java\Deployment\deployment.properties, but the records I add to this file get disappeared every time I run the java applet from the browser.

**A question: what is the right location for deployment.properties in this case?**

Thanks,
Racoon

Comment: Some info here. https://www.itninja.com/question/what-s-the-use-of-the-deployment-properties-file-when-you-install-java

Comment: @SJuan76, thank you!